# combine perl command inside the bash script

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Perl is excellent language to store command output to variable
As I know bash isn’t support that

for example

```
my $value = qx(ls -ltr);
print $value;
```

it will print: ( example )

```
 -r-xr-xr-x 1 root     root          761 May 30  2014 ASon.conf
 -r-xr-xr-x 1 root     root          699 May 30  2014 ascpl
 drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root         4096 Feb 24 13:22 da
 drwx------ 2 root     root         4096 Feb 25 08:08 vm-root
 drwxr-x--- 2 root     root         4096 Feb 25 08:10 hspeoot
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         2451 Feb 25 16:12 gry.txt
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         3112 Mar  1 09:49 new.xml
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        44893 Mar  1 12:13 SMports.xml
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root          101 Mar  2 09:56 test
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root    461340404 Mar  2 10:20 audin.log
```

the problem is that I write my code with bash
and I want to use the Perl add value in my bash script

so is it possible to combine the following line in my bash script?

```
  my $value = qx(ls -ltr);
```

in way that when I print the **value** variable it will print the **ls -ltr** output

Comment: echo $value total 451052 -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 761 May 30 2014 ASCBMon.conf -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 699 May 30 2014 ascbmon.pl drwxr-xr-x 2 roog ( this print one long line ) not as I want , and cat $value not illegale

Comment: You need to put double quotes around `"$value"` when you echo it, otherwise the white space will be lost.

Comment: WOW its work - write your answer - so I will can vote and select your answer,

Comment: I'd suggest not mixing and matching between two scripting languages unless there's a particularly compelling need. That's a road to confusion and maintenance headaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need perl for this, your shell can handle it:

```
value=$(ls -ltr)
echo "$value"
```

The quotes when you echo are important.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl:

```
$var = `shell command`;
$var = qx( shell command );
```

In `sh`:

```
var=`shell command`
var=$( shell command )
```